# Bash script to compile and run multiple servers and clients c

Tags: c++, multithreading, bash, shell, client-server

I'm writing a C++ client/server application, with a multithreaded server which accepts connections from multiple clients.
I need to write a bash script which compiles and executes multiple instances of both the server and the client. The client and the server are in different folders.

I tried this way, but it doesn't work because it starts only the server:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "/home/myhost/ServerSide"
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread server_struct.cpp -o server     
./server

cd "/home/myhost/ClientSide"
g++ -std=c++11 client.cpp -o client1
./client1

cd "/home/myhost/ClientSide"
g++ -std=c++11 client.cpp -o client2
./client2
```

Comment: Why do you need to **compile** the client executable multiple times?? Isn't it sufficient to compile once and start multiple instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally i would separate the build-process from running your applications.
furthermore, i would suggest to use `make` for building, rather than a bash-script.

Makefile (beware of indentation!):

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11

VPATH=ServerSide ClientSide

all: client server

server: server_struct.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
client: client.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
runall: server client
    xterm -e ./server &
    xterm -e ./client &
    xterm -e ./client &
```

and then simply run `make runall`